# Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Existing WooCommerce products are all gone and unable to install WooCommerce afresh.

The message showing while trying to install WooCommerce afresh:

Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
>   on line 24
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   ‘/home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php’
>   for inclusion (include_path=’.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear’) in
>   /home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
>   on line 24
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class ‘WooCommerce’ not found in
>   /home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php:34
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php(38):
>   WC() #1 /home/splendid/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2050):
>   include(‘/home/splendid/…’) #2
>   /home/splendid/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php(175):
>   plugin_sandbox_scrape(‘woocommerce/woo…’) #3 {main} thrown in
>   /home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
>   on line 34

Comment: Is the file there and uncorrupted? Can you manually extract the plugin into the right place, via shell or FTP?

Comment: File `/home/splendid/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php` was not found.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the plugin installation was borked for some reason. Best bet is to use FTP to transfer all plugin files from your local computer to the proper plugin folder. Check the plugin docs for help with a manual re-install so you don't overwrite a settings file, for instance.

Plugin help is best done through the plugin support area, though....not here.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, upgraded to GoDaddy Business Hosting Plan. To my pleasant surprise today, I could activate the WooCommerce plugin. Not sure the mystery behind my earlier removal of WooCommerce, then trying to install without success.

Comment: If that fixed it then I'd guess your new plan had more storage than your old plan and the class was failing to extract because your storage was full. But skimming GoDaddy's website it looks like all but the most expensive business plans have less storage? So don't know either!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a type of plugin conflict.
Try these solutions:

1. Update the plugin: Make sure your plugin is not outdated
2. Install the plugin manually.
3. Try to contact your plugin forum
   If you still getting this error. Try this video:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQijXeUKsWk&t=22s